# How to hide modal after submit button successfully clicked using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing issues is modal dismiss after submit button is successfully called using ajax call.

`$('#myModal').detach();
$('#myModal').remove();
$('#myModal').close();`

modal dismiss and not able to click anywhere

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Which version and did you look into the documentation on the APIs?

Comment: try  $('#myModal').modal('hide')

Answer (score 0):

According to the official bootstrap documentation at:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#methods

Please try:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```